# How to assign ng-model value in template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to make `ng-repeat` safe pagedown editor in simpler way using a template in a directive.

This is the demo.

http://plnkr.co/edit/TOhGV4?p=preview

As you see from the following code, I bind two variables

- uniqNum
- and, modelName

This is the code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.arr = ["1234567"];
});

app.directive('pagedownEditor', function($compile, $timeout) {
  var num=0;
  return {
    template:     
      '<div class="wmd-panel">'+
        '<div id="wmd-button-bar-{{uniqNum}}"></div>'+
        '<textarea ng-model="modelName" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-{{uniqNum}}">'+
        '</textarea>'+
      '</div>'+
      '<div id="wmd-preview-{{uniqNum}}" class="pagedown-preview wmd-panel wmd-preview">'+
      '</div>',
    link: function(scope, iElement, attrs) {
      if (scope.$index !== undefined) {
        //the following returns 'arr[0]'
        scope.modelName = Object.keys(scope.$parent).filter(function(el) {
          return (el[0]!=='$' && el !== "this")
        })[0] + '[' + scope.$index + ']';
        scope.uniqNum = scope.$index;
      } else if (attrs.ngModel) {
        scope.modelName = attrs.ngModel;
        scope.uniqNum = num++;
      }

      var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
      var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, "-" + scope.$index);
      $timeout(function() {editor.run();});
    }
  };
});
```

I have no problem setting uniqNum using {{uniqNum}}
However, if I set `ng-model="{{modelName}}"`, I have an error, `Error: [$parse:syntax]`.
If I set `ng-model="modelName"`, no error but ng-model value is modelName itself.

It should show `1234567` instead of variable name `arr[0]` in textarea.

From the above code, how do I set `ng-model="arr[0]"` using template?

Comment: So you want to automatically detect if `pagedownEditor` is in a `ng-repeat` or not. If it is in, `ng-model` should be `arr[$index]`. If not, `ng-model` should be `modelName`. Right?

Comment: Yes. I admit that it dose not look simple. It's better and simple to iterate textarea, but could not make it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/hFpWgI?p=preview

Basically you can use `$compile` to generate dynamic template according to the existence of `$index` property on scope. If `$index` is defined, the directive is inside a `ng-repeat`.

Also you have to use `track by` expression in `ng-repeat="str in arr track by $index"`. If not, every time value of arr[0] changes will cause ng-repeat to re-render the DOM.